# Build an object from another object in C# using generic code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection

Let's say I have an object of Type User that looks like this:

```
User {
   Name = "Bob",
   Email = "Bob@gmail.com",
   Class = NULL
}
```

Can anyone think of a way to take that object and create an object like this:

```
User {
   Name = "Bob",
   Email = "Bob@gmail.com"
}
```

Using entirely generic code?  Meaning, I don't want to hard code anything to do with the Type, or the Properties because this code would need to be applied to every Entity on my site.  (the "User" type is an Entity by the way, so use that if it helps you code this better).

I'm just trying to come up with a solution to a problem I have and I BELIEVE that [Stub Entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/19/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities.aspx) may fix the problem, but I need to do it without hard coding any Types or Properties.

Comment: Are those 2 different User types?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. The difference between the two is the presence of the Class field. Do you want to duplicate an object and remove any fields called "Class" or do you want something more general? Bottom line is you are going to need to do some sort of reflection.

Comment: They represent the same Entity.  Obviously my Entities are much more complex than that, but basically using Stub Entities I BELIEVE I can save a partial object to the database, but I want to remove any values set to NULL before saving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use reflection to achieve this:

```
public void CopyValues<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source, TTarget target)
{
    var sourceProperties = typeof(TSource).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead);

    foreach (var property in sourceProperties)
    {
        var targetProperty = typeof(TTarget).GetProperty(property.Name);

        if (targetProperty != null && targetProperty.CanWrite && targetProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(source, null);

            targetProperty.SetValue(target, value, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Generics are not gonna help you for this case. There might be some option in the Entity Framework but i am not really known with that.

It would however be possible using Reflection. You could try something like this:

```
public static void CopyProperties(object a, object b)
{
    if (a.GetType() != b.GetType())
        throw new ArgumentException("Types of object a and b should be the same", "b")

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in a.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (!property.CanRead || !property.CanWrite || (property.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0))
            continue;

        property.SetValue(b, property.GetValue(a, null), null);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind tough that this requires all the properties you want to copy to have both a public setter and getter. Also there is the difference between "deep copy" vs "shallow copy" wich means if sub-objects are also copied or only referenced. This example will only reference them so it would be a "shallow copy"

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem for reflection rather than generics (although generics can be used as a sneaky way of caching the strategy for reflection). Unless I misread it, you want to create a new instance and copy most of the members... Which reflection is good at, albeit relatively slow. You can improve the speed by using meta-programming; on the first run (per-type) generate an optimised version, perhaps using DynamicMethod or Expression, and store a typed delegate from that. Then just use the delegate.